# Rounded text stroke/outline that blends in together using css

Tags: css

What is the best way to achieve text stroke similar to this?
[image]

Something that I attempted but doesn't work well or have rounded edges and blends together.

```css
h1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  font-size: 14vw;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 55%;
  top: 50%;
  color: #c35037;
}
h1:before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.18em #000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
h1:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(title);
  z-index: 1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.12)));
  background: linear-gradient(left top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.12) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -0.02em -0.04em 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<h1 title="with everyone">with everyone</h1>
```

I'd like to find a way without using the title attr or position absolute.
Any ideas how to achieve like the example picture above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without SVG, *which is IMHO what to use*,  CSS is about half way to help. you can duplicate [text-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) or [drop-shadow filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()). But [-webkit-text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) won't do the job here .

demos of shadows/drop-shadow and failing text-stroke: All gives you an average render.

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
margin:0;border:solid 1px;
  color:#C35037;
  padding:0.5em;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:100px;
  background:#FAE0DA;
} h1{
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.2em white ,0 0 0.2em white, 0 0 0.3em white, 0 0 0.4em white;

}
h2 span { filter : 
  drop-shadow(0 0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 0.015em white)
  
  drop-shadow(0 -0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 -0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 -0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 -0.015em white)
  drop-shadow(0 -0.015em white)
  
  drop-shadow( -0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( -0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( -0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( -0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( -0.015em 0 white)
  
  drop-shadow( 0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( 0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( 0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( 0.015em 0 white)
  drop-shadow( 0.015em 0 white)

}

h3 {-webkit-text-stroke:0.05em white;}
```

```html
<h1 title="with everyone">with Everyone</h1>
<h2 title="with everyone"><span>with Everyone</span></h2>
<h3 title="with everyone">with Everyone</h3>
```

Comment: This is great thank you! The h1 option / the text-shadow is almost what I want. Is it possibly to have the text-shadow solid instead of blurred edges?
Or the h2 option using the drop-shadow but with rounded edges?

Comment: @drifterOcean19 to increase the crisp on the edge , you need to add a few more shadows , the translucide part will become less and less translucide every time there is a new shadow layer. that's about it :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you need SVG filters.

So first create a svg filter using svg tag like this:

```html
<svg>
   <filter id="gooey">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" />
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 500 -5" />
   </filter>
</svg>
```

Using the data attribute we will set the same text and access it using `attr()` and set it inside `:before` element and apply the filter to the before element, like this:

```html
<div data-text="Heading" class="text">
    <span>
        Heading
    </span>
</div>
```

```css
div.text:before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    filter: url(#gooey);
}
```

You also need to adjust the letter spacing, positions for both the heading as well as the before element to adjust the texts.

The main magic resides in the `<feColorMatrix>`, to know more about it read this article: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/#about-color-matrices.

The value 500 and -5 will make the effect possible. 500 gets multiplied by the alpha channel and then `-5 * 255` will be subtracted from that value.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  background: #fae0d9;
}

div.text {
/*  font-family: sans-serif; */
    font-size: 5rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #c35037;
}

div > span {
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
  left: 2px;
}

div.text:before {
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 5.5rem;
    filter: url(#gooey);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-text="Heading" class="text">
    <span>
        Heading
    </span>
</div>
<svg>
  <filter id="gooey">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 300 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Here's the full article: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/